# How to classify Data frame of characters into categories using keywords in R?

Tags: r, nlp, classification, keyword

I'm trying to classify a data frame of customer reviews into the respective categories. For example,

```
x <- data.frame(Reviews = c("The phone performance and display is good","Worth the money","Camera is good"))
```

The desired output is as below image

[image: Please click for image]

I tried creating a dictionary as below using R's Quanteda package

```
dic <- dictionary(list(camera = c("camera","lens","pixel", "pictures", 
"pixels", "snap"), display = c("resolution", "display", "depth", "mode", 
"color", "colour", "discolour"), performance = c("performance", "speed", 
"usage", "fast", "run", "running", "lag", "processor", "shut", "shut down", 
"restart", "hanging","hang"), Value = c("money", "worth", "budget", "value", 
"price", "specs", "specifications", "invest", 
"under","expectations","expected","expecting","expect")))
```

I would like to classify the texts based on keywords as stated above. Please help

P.S : dfm is one option. But particularly, I would like to know how to classify a data frame of texts as per the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Using already most of your code:

```
# Creating a DFM and saving the Reviews in a Vector
require("quanteda")
x <- dfm( Reviews <- c(
        "The phone performance and display is good",
        "Worth the money",
        "Camera is good"),
          tolower = TRUE)
```

I converted the capital letters to lowercase, otherwise, the fixed comparison would not work. Further, I recommend stopword removal and some kind of steaming.

```
# Creating the dictionary
dic <- dictionary(list(camera = c("camera","lens","pixel", "pictures", "pixels", "snap"), 
                       display = c("resolution", "display", "depth", "mode", "color", "colour", "discolour"), 
                       performance = c("performance", "speed", "usage", "fast", "run", "running", "lag", "processor", "shut", "shut down", "restart", "hanging","hang"), 
                       Value = c("money", "worth", "budget", "value", "price", "specs", "specifications", "invest", "under","expectations","expected","expecting","expect")))
```

Using the `dfm_lookup` function:

```
# fixed parameter fof exact matching
res <- dfm_lookup(x, dic, valuetype = "fixed")
row.names(res)<- Reviews
res
```

Hope this is what you are looking for :)